# Add programs in the Windows context menu for a specific category of files (all video formats for example)

Tags: windows-10, video, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm trying to figure out how to edit the context menu of the Windows File Explorer to add custom programs for a specific category of files, for example all video formats or all image formats.

I have *VLC* installed and it has a contextual action "Play with VLC" when I click on a video file. I just installed *mpv* and want to do the same. I know I can add a mpv action for every video file format one by one but it's too long, I can't do this manually.

So is there a way to include all video formats at once in the Windows registry? Or at least is it possible to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Shell" subkey under:
`HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\video`
and add you context item there.

You can examine:

- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\audio\shell`
- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell`
- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell`

for examples.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer although your solution doesn't work with `.mkv`, `.mp4`, `.ogv`, or `.webm` files for example. The only video file I found to work is `.avi`.